# Where can i find towitoko library?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I tried to install the gem ctapi:

```
gem install ctapi
Fetching: ctapi-0.2.3.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ctapi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Using default library towitoko!
checking for main() in -ltowitoko... no
```

On the site of the gem it says:

*You need to install a driver library, that supports the CTAPI interface for this     extension to link against. The newest version of the towitoko library, that is required to drive the Towitoko Chipdrive Micro, Extern, Extern II, Intern, Twin, and the "Kartenzwerg", can be download at this URL: http://www.geocities.com/cprados*

The problem is that the url is not avaible! Does somebody know antoher place where i can find this libaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian seems to have a mirror of the source code here:

- http://packages.debian.org/en/sid/libtowitoko-dev

Direct link to `towitoko_2.0.7.orig.tar.gz`:

- http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/towitoko/towitoko_2.0.7.orig.tar.gz

Comment: Sorry but can you explaine me how to install this liabries on windows?

Comment: Or better question, can i use this libary with win32?

Comment: Have you built a program from source before?

Comment: Actually i am not sure if it works on win, but it might very well be the case.